# How to use comparison principle to prove the following inequality about Laplace equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Assume that $\Omega$ is a bounded connected domain and $\partial \Omega\in C^{\infty}$. Denote $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\cdots,\Gamma_n$ are $n$ connected components of $\partial\Omega$. This notation leads to $\partial \Omega=\cup^n_{i=1}\Gamma_i$. Consider the following problem.
\begin{cases}
\Delta \phi&=0\\
\phi|_{\partial \Omega}&=g(x),\quad g\in C^{\infty}
\end{cases}
Denote $\mathcal{S}$ is subset of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ and $\mathcal{S}^c$ is $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}\setminus \mathcal{S} $. If we know that
$$
\min_{i\in \mathcal{S}}\inf_{x\in \Gamma_i}\phi(x)\ge \max_{i\in \mathcal{S}^c} \sup_{x\in \Gamma_i} \phi(x)+\delta,
$$ where $\delta$ is a positive constant,
how to prove that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}}\int_{\Gamma_i}\nabla \phi\cdot \vec{n}d\sigma>0?
\end{align*}
where $\vec{n}$ denotes the outer normal of $\partial \Omega$.

**My effort:** I meet this question when I read a paper. This paper say that it is a standard comparison principle exercise, but I still don't know how to solve this question. When $g(x)$ is a step function, we may consider Hopf Lemma or strong maximum principle. However, $g$ is a function. Any comments will be welcome.
[the equation (2.51) of page 2992 in this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-170/issue-13/Symmetry-in-stationary-and-uniformly-rotating-solutions-of-active-scalar/10.1215/00127094-2021-0002.full)

Comment: Does $\Omega$ have any regularity? I believe you can just use the Hopf Lemma, but this requires that $\partial \Omega$ at least satisfies the interior ball condition.

Comment: @JackT Thanks for your comments! I have add some condition on the regularity of $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: This question have solved in MOF, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433521/how-to-use-comparison-principle-to-prove-the-following-inequality-about-laplace/433536#433536